# How to Display Topic by User Subscription to Topic Category

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm new to Django Python framework.
i have the Topic model, SubChannel model, SubChannelSubscription model.

i want to display the Topics according to what the user subscribed to.
For example, If a User subscribed to Physics category only, the User should only see Physics Topics

Python 3 and Django 2

```
class SubChannelSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subscriptions',
                             verbose_name='Subscriber', default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubChannel, related_name='Topic+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   verbose_name='SubChannel', default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%(user)s\'s subscription to "%(category)s"' % {'user': self.user, 'category': self.category}

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name = 'Subscription to SubChannel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subscriptions to SubChannel'


class Topic(models.Model):
    by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubChannel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=True, related_name='topics')
    file = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Topic_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I have my Views.py code for User Subscription shown below

```
class SubChannelSubscriptionView(ListView):
    template_name = 'subscription.html'
    model = Topic

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return SubChannelSubscription.objects.filter(user=self.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SubChannelSubscriptionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['topics'] = self.user
        context['top'] = Topic.objects.filter(category=1)
        return context
```

my urls.py

```
path('subscription/<int:pk>', SubChannelSubscriptionView.as_view(), name='subscription'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case it looks like:

```
Topic.objects.filter(category__Topic+__user=self.user)
```

But I recommend to rename `related_name` of `category` field to a better name, for example:

```
class SubChannelSubscription(models.Model):
    ....
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        SubChannel, 
        related_name='subchannel_subs', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='SubChannel', 
        default=True
    )
```

If you have that changes the query will look like:

```
Topic.objects.filter(category__subchannel_subs__user=self.user)
```

And you can do

```
context['top'] = Topic.objects.filter(category__subchannel_subs__user=self.user)
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. If you don't mind can you explain the last code snippet

Comment: In `Topic` mode first you access *category* field which relates to `SubChannel` model. Then you access *subchannel_subs* which is related_name to `SubChannelSubscription` and in that model yon access *user* field which you compare with `self.user`. And you have `category__subchannel_subs__user=self.user` in filter.